# UIImagePickerViewConroller get photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this mechanism to get photo from the photos library.
the problem that i have is that photo i get from

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

are vertical for all the photos, there is a way to rotate the images by the way the photos was taken, beacuse i want to show this photos in the screen but i get them in the opposite.

Comment: I think you should check this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989087/uiimagepickercontroller-returning-incorrect-image-orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past!! You need to use the EXIF information stored in the photo and rotate based on the orientation specified when taking the picture.

There is a great [article here with full source code.](http://www.gotow.net/creative/wordpress/?p=64)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`from the `info` dictionary