# How to save photos taken using AVFoundation to Photo Album?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, avfoundation

AVFoundation is just great for those who want to get hands dirty, but there still a lot of basic stuff not easy to figure like how to save the pictures taken from device to Photo Album

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't appear that this topic involves Cocoa.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is a step by step tutorial on how to capture an image using `AVFoundation` and save it to photo album.

Add a `UIView` object to the NIB (or as a subview), and create a `@property` in your controller:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *vImagePreview;
```

Connect the `UIView` to the outlet above in IB, or assign it directly if you’re using code instead of a NIB.

Then edit your `UIViewController`, and give it the following `viewDidAppear` method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
    [self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}
```

Create a new `@property` to hold a reference to output object:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
```

Then make a `UIImageView` where we’ll display the captured photo. Add this to your NIB, or programmatically.

Hook it up to another `@property`, or assign it manually, e.g.;

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *vImage;
```

Finally, create a `UIButton`, so that you can take the photo.

Again, add it to your NIB (or programmatically to your screen), and hook it up to the following method:

```
-(IBAction)captureNow {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) 
            { 
                break; 
            }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
    {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
            // Do something with the attachments.
            NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         } else {
            NSLog(@"no attachments");
             }

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        self.vImage.image = image;

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
     }];
}
```

You might have to import `#import <ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h>` also.

[Source](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/). Also check [this](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297).

Comment: I will strongly recommend others to visit the websites linked in this post. They give a deeper insight in what is happening. Great post, iDev!

Comment: Worked great. Maybe [super viewDidAppear:animated] should be called also.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have it's Swift version code. Anyone need, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, looks like you've already got the picture from the camera into NSData or UIImage. If so, you can add this picture to the album in differrent ways. AVFoundation itself doesn't have classes which are carrying the holding of the images.
So, for example, you can use the [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) framework to save image to the Photo Album.
Or you can use just UIKit framework with it's [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) method. Both are good to use.

In case that you don't have still image captured yet, you can look at the [captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009552) method of the AVFoundation framework.
Anyway, here are the ideas. You can find examples in the Internet easily.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to setting up the camera this way that you either aren't doing or aren't showing.

The best place to look would be at: [`AVCamCaptureManager.m`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Classes_AVCamCaptureManager_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Classes_AVCamCaptureManager_m-DontLinkElementID_4) in the the AVCam sample project; particularly `setupSession` and `captureStillImage` (which writes the photo to the library).

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me

```
-(void) saveImageDataToLibrary:(UIImage *) image
{
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
[appDelegate.library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageData metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Photo saved successful");
    }
}];
}
```

where appDelegate.library is `ALAssetLibrary` instance.

Comment: thanks, but how did you extract the UIImage from the front camera device using AVFoundation?