# How Can i change image quality when using AVCaptureSessionPreset

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, avfoundation, avcapturesession

im looking for some help with AVFoundation. Currently i have following a step by step guide on how to capture a still image from this topic: [How to save photos taken using AVFoundation to Photo Album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106486/how-to-save-photos-taken-using-avfoundation-to-photo-album)

My question is, how can i lower the quality of my saved image as well as using the AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480. I would like to half the image quality, or if there is another way to make the saved image as small a file as possible - possibly 320x280 - then that could be better than adjusting the actual quality.

I dont know if anyone else has asked this before or not but i have been searching the web for the past couple of days and cannot find an answer. Below is my code.

`

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imagePreview;
@synthesize iImage;
@synthesize stillImageOutput;

-(IBAction)captureNow {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         } else {
             NSLog(@"no attachments");
         }

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         //NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f)]];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         self.iImage.image = image;

         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
     }];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

    CALayer *viewLayer = self.imagePreview.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.imagePreview.bounds;
    [self.imagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Try using different Preset that will give you different resolution image.

As per the Apple Documentation, for iPhone4(Back) you will get the following resolution image for the following Preset for that session.

`AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh : 1280x720`

`AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium : 480x360`

`AVCaptureSessionPresetLow : 192x144`

`AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 : 640x480`

`AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 : 1280x720`

`AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto : 2592x1936.This is not supported for video output`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am already using the AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 which is giving me a file size of about 84kb, i'm looking to half that size as i will be sending the image to a web service to check and i need it to be as small as possible for processing time.

Comment: I haven't tried it for the size of an image but you can try this image = [image resizedImage:CGSizeMake(width, height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationLow];
Using this you can set the size of your image and quality.Other options for interpolationQuality are kCGInterpolationMedium, kCGInterpolationHigh, kCGInterpolationNone

Comment: I'll try that out, but i have code like this:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f) being used before which changes the quality (1.0f is 100%, so if i wanted 50% it would be 0.5f) but i'm unsure on how to implement that with avfoundation.

Comment: Whenever you get NSData to UIImage and then write above line for UIIMageJPEGRepresentaion..

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `kCVPixelBufferWidthKey` and `kCVPixelBufferHeightKey` options on `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` object to set resolution of your choice.  This width/height will override session preset width/height. Minimal sample as below (add error check).

```
    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError * error;
    _sessionInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    _stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:320.0], (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithDouble:280.0], (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                              nil];

    [_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:options];

    [_session beginConfiguration ];
    [_session addInput:_sessionInput];
    [_session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
    [_session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
     _avConnection = [_stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [ _session commitConfiguration ];

.............

- (void) start
{
    [self.session startRunning];
}

.............

[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:self.avConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
     size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
     size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
     NSLog(@"%d : %d", height, width);

 }];
```

Note: I have only tried this on an mac. Ideally it should work for iOS too. Also try maintaining some aspect ratio.