# ios7 uiimagepickercontroller showscameracontrol

Tags: camera, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController on iOS7.
I don't want to use basic camera controls, so I set showsCameraControl=NO;
So, I can see not full screen uiimagepickercontroller on my iPhone5s.
The Camera View frame size is that the size before setting showsCameraControl.

And here is my code that define UIImagePickerController in MainViewController

```
CustomCamera *imagePickerController = [[CustomCamera alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

'CustomCamera' is almost same as UIImagePickerController class(has .xib).

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the class reference for [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode
>   only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support
>   subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not
>   be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

If you have modifications you wish to make, it must be done solely via `cameraOverlayView` property. Otherwise, you could use AVFoundation do accomplish this if you want total control over how things look.

[How to save photos taken using AVFoundation to Photo Album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106486/how-to-save-photos-taken-using-avfoundation-to-photo-album)