# iOS Image Orientation is getting changed after converting to base 64 string

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.3.2 and swift 3.1 in one of my application when I am converting the camera image into base64 and posting to server.In server the base 64 string is converted to image which gets rotated by 90 degree left I try so many method to fix this issue but did not working any one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Image Orientation has Strange Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600613/ios-image-orientation-has-strange-behavior)

Comment: i have tried the options given in the above page,but no luck!!

Answer (score 1):

The orientation is stored separate from the image data in

```
UIImage.imageOrientation
```

Comment: I have tried to change the orientation to up and tried to convert the base string which dint work too.

Comment: Based on what imageOrientation is you need to orientate the image data yourself.

Comment: I have tried to rotate the image and then converted to base64 but still no luck! How can we  rotate the image data?? any idea is that possible?